# IPTables issue: Can't connect to mongodb w/ mongo shell - CentOS

Tags: mongodb, shell, centos, iptables

I'm having issues connecting to my mongo shell. I can connect successfully when I remove all directives from my IPTables. CentOS 6.5, mongod is running. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
[samir@core ~]$ mongo 127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
Wed Mar 12 00:42:12.193 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed
```

I also tried to start with just mongo.

Mongod is running:

```
[samir@core ~]$ sudo service mongod start
Starting mongod: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 2104
all output going to: /var/log/mongo/mongod.log
child process started successfully, parent exiting
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

The mongo log does not give any pointed either:

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.634 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2104 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=core.datafit.io
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.634 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.634 [initandlisten] git version: 52fe0d21959e32a5bdbecdc62057db386e4e029c
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.634 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.634 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.634 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongo", fork: "true", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongo/mongod.log", pidfilepath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.639 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongo/journal
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.640 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.725 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongo/local.ns, filling with zeroes...
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.725 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongo/_tmp
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.738 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongo/local.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0.011 secs
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.738 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongo/local.0, filling with zeroes...
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.753 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongo/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.014 secs
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.755 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Wed Mar 12 00:44:30.756 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
```

My IPTables looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 49 packets, 3315 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1665  130K ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    2   128 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
   18  1080 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:27017 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:28017 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 987 packets, 156K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

If I set the INPUT directive to ACCEPT, mongo shell works:

```
[samir@core db]$ sudo mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
>
```

Netstat -pln | rep 27017:

```
[samir@core db]$ sudo netstat -pln | grep 27017 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2178/mongod         
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12125  2178/mongod         /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Something must be wrong with my iptables input policies. Any ideas?

Comment: netstat -pln | grep 27017

what's the result of this?

Comment: @yaoxing here's the result:

'tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2178/mongod         
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12125  2178/mongod         /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock'

Answer (score 1):

You migth want to try, substituting the line

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

With

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```